# iwconfig: wlan0 no wireless extensions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, wlan, iw

I've some problems with the wlan0 interface on an embedded linux distro (compiled with yocto). The problem is that when I use the command:

```
iwconfig
```

the wlan0 results with no wireless extensions. But if I write the command:

```
iw wlan0 scan
```

it works correctly! And it also works well if I use `connman` as connection manager instead of `iwconfig`. I've tried to get up the interfaces with the follow commands:

```
ip link set wlan0 up
```

or

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

but when I checked the status of the file in `/sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate` the result is always "down". How can I solve this problem?

i want that `iwconfig` recognize the wlan0 interface.

Comment: Try to install ma dkms with required driver extension. You can find it in the apt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like either your kernel or the driver for the wireless interface will only support the newer `cfg80211` configuration interface used by the `iw` tool, not the older `wireless-extensions` interface used by `iwconfig`.

Does your kernel configuration enable the `CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT` option, and/or the `CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT` option? The latter option will enable a compatibility layer that will allow old userspace programs like `iwconfig` to access the configuration of newer-style drivers.

Note that when you use `ip link set wlan0 up` or `ifconfig wlan0 up` you'll be setting the *administrative state* of the interface, or basically the state the interface will *want* to be in. The `/sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate` tells you about the *operational state* of the interface, i.e. what state the interface has *actually managed to achieve.*

For a wired interface, the operational state changes to `up` basically reflects the state of the link LED of the interface: when the interface detects the link pulses from the other end (and successfully negotiates the connection speed and other parameters, if applicable), the link LED will light, and the operational state will change to `up`.

A wireless interface has no cable to plug in, so the equivalent task is associating with a wireless network (and completing any necessary authentication, if applicable). So you should first configure the wireless interface with a network with an ESSID and any necessary network passwords or authentication keys. If the wireless interface is out of range of the wireless AP or the authentication settings are not correct, the wireless interface won't be able to actually transfer packets - and that's what the operational state "down" means.

Comment: thank you!! i'm trying to develop a librarie,  that use netlink socket instead of ioctl, thanks to your answer!